# Woocommerce get_cart_subtotal() value contains HTML entities interfering with value sanitization process

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, replace, html-entities

I'm trying to strip the tags and remove extraneous characters from the value returned from Woocommerce's `get_cart_subtotal()` method, but I can't manage to get it in the correct format. Something is fishy.

I'm using `WC()->cart->get_cart_subtotal();` to retrieve the value. In this example my value is `2,429kr` and the raw returned value is `<span class="amount">2,429kr</span>`

```
$cart_total = WC()->cart->get_cart_subtotal();
$cart_total_format = strip_tags($cart_total);
$cart_value = preg_filter("/[^0-9,.]/", "", $cart_total_format);

echo $cart_value;
```

**Result** = 2,429107114
**Expected** = 2,429

I'm not a PHP wizard so I thought I was doing something wrong and did try several different approaches and methods without getting the correct result.

Then I did try to output the raw string value from `WC()->cart->get_cart_subtotal();`

```
$string_total = '<span class="amount">2,429kr</span>';
$string_total_format = strip_tags($string_total);
$string_value = preg_filter("/[^0-9,.]/", "", $string_total_format);

echo $string_value;
```

**Result** = 2,429
**Expected** = 2,429

Why? :(

**Update**

I found this while digging around in Woocommerce's source code:

```
case 'SEK' : $currency_symbol = '&#107;&#114;'; break;
```

So the real value is:

```
<span class="amount">2,429&#107;&#114;</span>
```

The question now is what is the best approach to filter this out? My quick fix approach is as follows; it's not beautiful but fixes the issue.

```
$cart_total = WC()->cart->get_cart_subtotal();
$cart_total_format = strip_tags($cart_total);
$cart_value = preg_filter("/[^0-9,.]/","", $cart_total_format);
$cart_value_new = preg_filter("/107114/",".", $cart_value);

echo $cart_value_new;
```

**Result** = 2,429
**Expected** = 2,429

Comment: First of all, your regexes are different. The first one doesn't include the thousands and decimals separator, but I guess you did include them in your code.
And, just be absolutely sure, if you `var_dump($cart_total)` after the first line, you get `string(35) "<span class="amount">2,429kr</span>"`, right?

Comment: Yes that was a typo, have edit my post. 

`var_dump($cart_total);` Gives `string(45) "2,429kr"`

No Matter with or without the html it would still work and result in the same expected value

Comment: `string(45) "2,429kr"` should be `string(7) "2,429kr"`

Comment: Don't that have to do with chosen currency? Am not really good at php so just a guess.

Comment: Unless you want to reduce the value to `null` when no replacement is performed, you should be using`preg_replace()` instead of `preg_filter()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so this is what is happening. `get_cart_subtotal()` returns an HTML-encoded string. Because you are not looking at the actual source, but rather `var_dump`-ing it and looking at the HTML you are seeing `<span class="amount">2,429kr</span>`, when in fact the "k" and "r" are encoded into their equivalent HTML entities (based on their [ASCII codes](http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif)), `&#107;` and `&#114`.

That is also why `var_dump` shows `string(45) "2,429kr"` when it should in fact return `string(7) "2,429kr"` if the currency weren't encoded (and the `<span>` tags weren't interpreted by the browser).

Then, when you apply the `preg_filter`, it also includes the numbers from the HTML entities, of course, because they match the regular expression.

So the easiest solution is to decode all HTML entities **before** filtering:

```
$cart_total = html_entity_decode($cart_total, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

so your code becomes:

```
$cart_total = WC()->cart->get_cart_subtotal();
$cart_total = html_entity_decode($cart_total, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
// rest of your code
```

Comment: Could you give me the whole snippet for that. Did try it but did not get it to produce the correct result, would like to see it work.

Comment: Just add my code after you call `get_cart_subtotal()`, between the first and second lines in your code.

Comment: I have added another snippet to my answer to show exactly where to enter the new line of code.

Comment: Did mess something up when i tested myself, Now it's working!

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess:

Maybe  `WC()->cart->get_cart_subtotal()` return `'<span class="amount">2,429107114kr</span>'`, but when you display it you see `<span class="amount">2,429kr</span>` because of some javascript that round it.

Comment: You are something on the track, Have not found any Javascript yet but found this in my code where price value was commented out 

`<!--
<span class="price"><span class="amount">179&#107;&#114;</span></span>
-->`


Did run this `<!-- <?php echo $cart_total;?> -->` and got this `<!--
<span class="amount">2,429&#107;&#114;</span>-->`

Basically `&#107;&#114` is added as currency

Running `<span class="amount">2,429&#107;&#114;</span>` gives 2,429kr