# If PHP value in equation have ending zeros it get stripped

Tags: php, wordpress

Was changing my thousand decimal from "," to "." and can't solve how to not get one of my values not to strip away zeros in end of value and i can't understand why.

An example to describe me case would be this

```
$value_1 = '25.000';
$value_2 = '4.920';
```

If i echo this two values is will produce

```
<?php echo $value_1;?> / <?php echo $value_2;?>
```

25.000 / 4.920

Everything is okay this far. Then am doing an equation

```
$sum = $value_1 - $value_2;
```

And here is where it goes wrong

```
echo $sum;
```

Produce: **20.08** where the correct value should have been 20.080

But if the equation would have an sum with a value that is not a zero. For example if we change one of the values to produce a sum that contain something else then a zero it would play out like this

```
$value_1 = '25.000';
// Adding +1 to original code to get the sum of 2079
$value_2 = '4.921';  

$sum = $value_1 - $value_2;

echo $sum;
```

Produce: **20.079**

In my code i have been running several tests where i echo out values to make sure that everything is correct until the equation. I don't understand the logic. Or i understand that what is my thousands separator is in the sum from the equation threaten as a decimal, but then i don't understand why that is not happening anywhere else.

Worth to mention is that it's running on an Woocommerce site that is set to use "." as thousand separator and "," for decimals but with 0 decimals written out. Every where on site i get values correct.

If i run the values without thousand separator like:

```
 $value_1 = '25000';
 $value_2 = '4920';
```

The sum would be written out as 20080 so with that knowledge it can't be Woocommerce that tampers with my result.

Best would be to find the solution but because am only using this code on one place am not completely foreign to first stripping away the thousand separator "." from my values and after the equation restore it again.

Comment: `25.000` is 25, not 25 thousands. Look into number formatting and localization.

Comment: The 0 on the right hand side, has not value, that why this is omitted. What you have to do is format the result if you want to include 0 at the end there is str_pad($result,20,"0",STR_PAD_RIGHT);

Comment: Check out http://in3.php.net/number_format

Comment: Another thing could be that you confuse . with , and you want one as decimal separator and the other as thousand separator, in that case you have to define your current locale on the php settings.

Comment: In this case "." is thousands separator and "," is decimal but the setup is that no decimals i printed.  Of Course "," would be the thousands separator but this is not my decision.

Comment: Please read [PHP String conversion to numbers](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion): "*If the string does not contain any of the characters '.', 'e', or 'E' and the numeric value fits into integer type limits (as defined by PHP_INT_MAX), the string will be evaluated as an integer. **In all other cases it will be evaluated as a float**.*".

Comment: I understand, but that is a presentation matter. Behind the scenes (i.e. in PHP code), `.` is the decimal separator. Nothing you can do about that.

Comment: Thanks for information. @sudo.ie you mention php settings, where is this set, in the local php.ini?

Comment: @X.L.Ant Okay that i can understand and will take with me. But in this case one of the values in this equation is the customers current value in shopping cart and Woocoomerce would supply me this value with "." as thousand separator because that's set in the settings of woocommerce. What would be the most legit way to do it after the book. The solution below with number_format or formating my value from Woocommerce back to "," and then format my $sum back to "." ? :)

Comment: I don't know Woocomerce, isn't there a way to get unformatted values out of it ?

Comment: @X.L.Ant Not what i know about, Had a question earlier regarding this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25993634/php-preg-filter-returns-unexpected-long-value 

So my value is already stipped out of letters and html where this question starts and that's why i asked because i could have switched "." for "," when doing my preg_filter. Just interesting to know what would be the "correct" way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's working correctly.  The answer to the subtraction is a number to two decimal places.  If you want to force it to show three, use number_format:

```
echo number_format($sum, 3);
```

More info here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Comment: Thanks, Will read up on that and save myself a couple of hours some time php:in in the future!